# Processing file uploaded by jquery fileupload

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-file-upload

I've followed the tutorial for jquery fileupload the code I've written is below

```
$('#image_file').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    url: '/whats-on/upload-event/?v='+event_id,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    done: function (e, data) {
        console.log('done');
    }
});
```

It returns an error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Here's the python function it fails when it tries

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_event(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    response_data = {}
    response_data['status'] = False
    if request.FILES:
        file = request.FILES[u'files']
        response_data['status'] = True
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
```

It doesn't go through `request.FILES` and fails when it reaches `data = json.loads(request.body)`

Comment: open the developer console and see what the actual eerror is